# Use Obfuscated dll as reference in c# project

Tags: c#, obfuscation

For confidentiality reasons I need to create a solution which will use several obfuscated DLL (obfuscated with ConfuseEx) for consultants.

I've referenced the dll in my project but when I try to use public elements of my obfuscated dll in code, visual studio static code analysis mark those in red with the following error: "Cannot resolve symbol '[ClassName]'".

When I build and run the project it works fine

It is not very convenient to code without code completion an without any information about the dll.
How can I do to use the obfuscated dll like every other dll in visual studio with object recognition

PS: the object viewer works fine on the dll and display correctly public elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscation should be done after build.
Because an Obfuscator randomizes names

With the open source [confuser tool](https://confuser.codeplex.com/) you can disable Name confusion

Comment: Thanks for the answer. only internal names are confused. All Public elements which are used outside the dll are not so logically visual studio should recognize these , isn't it ?